# How to tell Spark Workers do not give up finding master?

Tags: configuration, apache-spark

The machines in our cluster will restart due to software updates from time to time, so we wrote scripts to start Spark Workers and Master automatically.

However, if workers cannot see Master for a certain amount of time, they will give up and shut down eventually. So if the Master machine get restarted, the workers will get time out and shut down before they successfully connect to the restarted master.

So, the problem is, how to tell the workers do not give up connecting to the master?

Thank you!

Comment: What's the message from the workers when they shut down? There are `spark.rpc.numRetries` (default: 3) - the number of times to retry connection attempts and `spark.rpc.retry.wait` (default: 3s) - the number of milliseconds to wait on each retry that you could possibly use.

Comment: They say "All masters are unresponsive! Giving up." @JacekLaskowski I'll try the parameters you've told me, thx!